# I want 2 widgets to be aligned on the Left screen and One widget on the right screen. How Can I achieve that

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**I want my checkBox and Remember password on the left screen and forgot Password  on the right Screen..TextAlign is not working since it require space and using SizedBox won't be dynamic. What is the best way**

```
Row(
            children: [
              Checkbox(
                value: isChecked,
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    isChecked = value!;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Text(
                'Remember Password',
              ),
              Text(
                'Forgot Password',
                ),
              
            ],
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Spacer(),

```
Row(
  children: [
    Checkbox(
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        });
      },
    ),
    Text(
      'Remember Password',
    ),
    Spacer(),
    Text(
      'Forgot Password',
      ),
    
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

tried [mainAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html)?

```
 Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
         Row(children:[ Checkbox(
            value: isChecked,
            onChanged: (bool? value) {
              setState(() {
                isChecked = value!;
              });
            },
          ),
          Text(
            'Remember Password',
          )],
          Text(
            'Forgot Password',
            ),
          
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: No using mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, would give the space between the CheckBox and Text, I don't want that..Using Spacer() .. helped me ...But Thanks Benjith for helping me out